# VB.NET - Loop skipping Items in ListBox

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have a listbox with directories (not local, it is over a network) listed in it.
I am trying to loop through that listbox and remove any empty directories.
However, I noticed that it just skips some empty directories.. I found that if I ran the loop 3 - 5 times it will get them all, but that isn't very efficient.

My Loop:

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
While i < ListBox1.Items.Count
   If IO.Directory.GetFiles(ListBox1.Items.Item(i), "*.*").Length = 0 Then
      ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
   End If
i = i + 1
End While
```

So I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way to check the contents of the directory or another way i could achieve this without having to run the loop multiple times.

Comment: So the improvement that immediately comes to mind is "how are you filling ListBox1.Items with the items". If you never add them to the listbox, you don't have to remove them.

notionally: for each toAdd in (from itm in itemSource where IO.Directory.GetFiles(itm, "*.*").Length <> 0 ) ListBox1.Items.Add(toAdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListBox1.Items.Count` is getting reevaluated every time, making your loop get shorter as time goes on missing some items.  A quick solution could be just mark which items you want to remove as you loop.

```
Dim toRemove As New List(Of ListBoxItem)
For Each item as ListBoxItem in ListBox1.Items
   If IO.Directory.GetFiles(item, "*.*").Length = 0 Then
      toRemove.Add(item)
   End If
Next

For Each item as ListBoxItem in toRemove
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
Next
```

(there is probably a better way, but that's a quick solution off the top of my head)

Comment: Classic mistake in loops :) Hence why I try to avoid the use of "<" in loops. I want them to crash on logical errors. Just do i = i-1 after you delete an item.

Comment: These comments don't look right now after edit. For future readers: Just do what KDiTraglia has written. That will work straight away.

Comment: @WozzeC I don't remember writing anything about minus 1 =/

Comment: @Mattigins Oh, yeah I guess that would work as well, I probably wrote it and second guessed myself.

Comment: I wrote i = i - 1 as an answer to Mattigins comment. If he used your code he wouldn't have to. Mark this answer as solved and we can all go on with our lives :)